# Как в цикле пометить нужное кол-во элементов?

Tags: php, html, css

подскажите пожалуйста как можно на стороне **php** в цикле с **div** элементами пометить нужное кол-во элементов в этом цикле.

с помощью цикла на php и html+css делаю вот такое:

[image]

И на стороне сервера получаю число к примеру 2.
И нужно в цикле пометить (добавить класс done) 2 элемента к примеру так:

[image]

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно такое реализовать?

Comment: Несмотря на то что ответ вам помог, он был удалён модератором как [сгенерированный с помощью ChatGPT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: Используя JS, можно сделать так: https://jsfiddle.net/02zm6ra9/